# How do I set argument names and types for a function argument in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, function, types, arguments

In TypeScript you can set argument types, like this:

```
function x(y: string[], z?: Function)
```

How do you set types for the arguments of a function argument?

For example, here is what I'd imagine it'd look like:

```
function x(y: string[], z?: Function(a: any, b: any))
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are looking for types using the fat-arrow notation.

```
function foo(a: (s: string, n: number) => string): string {
    return a("hello", 10);
}
```

Comment: Please note that `(string, number) => string` is [probably not what you think it is](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-dont-i-get-type-checking-for-number--string-or-t--t).  In TypeScript you have to give (dummy) names to parameters in function signatures.  Your `string` and `number` are interpreted as names (of implied `any` type) and not types.  You likely mean something like `(s: string, n: number) => string` instead.

Comment: I second @jcalz warning! careful with those names, please change them they will just lead to confusion, that is not a function that takes `string` and `number` it's a function that takes `any` and `any` HUGE difference

Comment: You're right @jcalz, I was a bit too quick on the trigger, IDE warning laziness crept in.